# Selecting Switching IC's frequency

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm planning on using [UC2842](https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/UC2842/datasheet). Based on the datasheet, I can choose a frequency up to 500KHz. My question is based on what should I choose frequency. Should I go to higher frequencies or stick with the lower ones?
Another question is that how can I make sure the MOSFET I'm trying to use is suitable for this frequency? I want to use [STW9NK90Z](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stb9nk90z.pdf)

Comment: "based on what should I choose frequency" - based on your application. What is your application?

Comment: There is this desk with LED string and solder and etc which is being used for soldering. It needs a 25 Volts and at least 3 Amps supply. @SimSon

Comment: Choice of frequency and transistor will determine the efficiency and available current delivered by the converter. The optimization of switching converters fills entire books, so a general answer like you're expecting is not feasible here. If you're looking for a quick solution use the vendors reference design or pick one of their examples close to what you need.

Comment: @user1850479 thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Higher frequencies are generally less efficient, but need (physically) smaller inductors and capacitors. They also require more careful board component placement and layout and are more sensitive to parasitic elements.

If your application is not critical (load transient response in the mV range), then a lower frequency is a better choice. 200 kHz might be reasonable.

You also don't need a 900 V rated FET (with 1 Ω RDSON). Use a 60 V device with < 50 mΩ.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll stick with lower frequencies like you said. But, the voltage across the drain and source of the transistor will be much higher than 60V specially when there is a spike on the drain at the time it gets turned off.

Comment: You have a bad PCB layout (and inefficient circuit) if a 25 V supply generates 900 V.

Comment: Output doesn't generate 900 volts. It's the spike from the primary side of the transformer. Since it's switching.